# Get last inserted item per day

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Is there a feature in mongodb that I can use to get the last inserted item per day ? I have a collection where I need to get the last inserted item per day, the data is grouped on an hourly basis like in the structure below.

```
{
   timestamp: 2017-05-04T09:00:00.000+0000,
   data: {}
},
{
   timestamp: 2017-05-04T10:00:00.000+0000,
   data: {}
}
```

I thought about using a projection but I am not quite sure how I could do this.

Edit: Also, since mongodb stores data in UTC, I would like to account for the offset as well.

Comment: first, sort data on timestamp (from oldest to newest). Then, group document by day ( in a **`$group`** stage ) and keep the last `data` with **`$last`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) and use [`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) for the item, with rounding out the grouping key to each day:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$sort": { "timestamp": 1 } },
  { "$group": {
     "_id": {
       "$add": [
         { "$subtract": [
           { "$subtract": [ "$timestamp", new Date(0) ] },
           { "$mod": [
             { "$subtract": [ "$timestamp", new Date(0) ] },
             1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
           ]}
         ]},
         new Date(0)
       ]
     },
     "lastDoc": { "$last": "$$ROOT" }
  }}
])
```

So the sort makes things appear in order, and then the grouping `_id` is rounded for each day by some date math. You subtract the epoch date from the current date to make it a number. Use the modulus to round to a day, then add the epoch date to the number to return a `Date`.

So stepping through the math we have getting the timestamp value from the date with the `$subract` line. We do this a couple of times:

```js
{ "$subtract": [ "$timestamp", new Date(0) ] }

// Is roughly internally like
ISODate("2017-06-06T10:44:37.627Z") - ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z")
1496745877627
```

Then there is the modulo with `$mod` which when applied to the numeric value returns the difference. The 1000 milliseconds * 60 seconds * 60 * minutes * 24 hours gives the other argument:

```js
 { "$mod": [
   { "$subtract": [ "$timestamp", new Date(0) ] },
   1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
 ]}

 // Equivalent to 
 1496745877627 % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
 38677627
```

Then there is the wrapping `$subtract` of the two numbers:

```js
 { "$subtract": [
   { "$subtract": [ "$timestamp", new Date(0) ] },
   { "$mod": [
     { "$subtract": [ "$timestamp", new Date(0) ] },
     1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
   ]}
 ]}

 // Subtract "difference" of the modulo to a day
 // from the milliseconds value of the current date
 1496745877627 - 38677627

 1496707200000
```

Then add back to the epoch date value to create a date rounded to the current day, which to the aggregation pipeline basically looks like providing the millisecond value to the constructor:

```js
new Date(1496707200000)
ISODate("2017-06-06T00:00:00Z")
```

Which takes the timestamp value and subrtacts out the difference of the divisor from "one day" and ends up at the time at the "start of day".

Just using `$$ROOT` here to represent the whole document. But any document path provided to [`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) here provides the result.

Comment: Thanks but  could you explain the  grouping process a little more ? It did the trick btw after I replaced all the numbers with a single number

Comment: @Bazinga777 It should't make a difference really. Works fine for me in JavaScript and I do it all the time. Is it how the math works to round this to a "day" that you need to understand better than the current explanation?

Comment: Thing is I need to add an offset for each timezone. I missed that in my question

Comment: exactly, I want to know the math

Comment: @Bazinga777 Okay. That's about as long winded as I can make it without sounding like a lecture. Hope you learn something. So your timezone offset should go in where you are converting the current timestamp from the `Date` BSON type to a "numeric" type. Therefore in the same lines as where the repeated `$subtract` statements are used. Do that all the time as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I even figured out how to account for the offset now

Comment: @Bazinga777 Good for you. I actually have some code that also accounts for changes in daylight savings and creates different calculations via `$cond` given a date range that crosses the change somewhere. I think there is an answer floating around on here where I showed that, but can't seem to find it. Anyway, at least you have what you want for now.

Comment: I would appreciate any resources